# why do i get the Error Module not found: Can't resolve 'redux'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux I have created a demo wherein I have install react redux and redux

Folder Structure

```
  src
    js
      store
        index.js
      action
        index.js
      reducers
        index.js
      index.js  ///////**2**
  index.js ///////////  **1**
  App.js .... etc
```

In **1** index.js I have the following code

```
import index from "./js/index";
```

In **2** index.js I have the following code

```
   import store from "../js/store/index";
   import { addArticle } from "../js/actions/index";

   window.store=store;
   window.addArticle=addArticle;
```

packages are all updated
when I npm start I get the following error;

```
   ./src/js/store/index.js
   Module not found: Can't resolve 'redux' in 'E:\reacr-redux\src\js\store'
```

**js/store/index.js**

```
     import { createStore } from "redux";
     import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";

     const store=createStore(rootReducer);

     export default store;
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";
 const initialState={
articles:[]
 };
  const rootReducer= ( state = initialState ,  action ) => {
    switch(action.type){
    case ADD_ARTICLE:
    state.articles.push(action.payload);
    return state;
    default :
    return state;
    }
   };
    export default rootReducer;
```

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "reacr-redux",
"version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"mdbootstrap": "^4.5.15",
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
"react-redux": "^5.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "2.1.1"
 },
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",

 },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "react-app"
  },
 "browserslist": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not ie <= 11",
  "not op_mini all"
  ],
 "devDependencies": {
   "redux": "^4.0.1"
   }
  }
```

Can anyone lemme know whats happening I'm new to it where m I going wrong

Comment: What is in store/index.js ?

Comment: @Jihlavanka have updated

Comment: Does redux appear in your node_modules folder? Did you install it with `npm i redux`?

Comment: It just seems like you did not install redux. Try to run: npm install redux --save in folder where is package.json

Comment: @FrankerZ yea i does

Comment: @Jihlavanka i had installed please check updated code

Comment: You have it in dev dependencies. It must be in normal dependencies in package.json - next to react-dom etc.

Comment: @Jihlavanka I  have used npm install --save redux   and npm i redux --save-dev is it correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do not use `save-dev` for Redux. Remove it from `devDependencies`:

```
npm uninstall redux --save-dev
```

and install it again with:

```
npm i redux --save
```

Comment: Why? Do you have any particular reason for this case?

Answer (score 14):

Simply installing the [react toolkit](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#redux-toolkit) should fix the problem.

```
# NPM
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit

# Yarn
yarn add @reduxjs/toolkit
```

Answer (score 2):

after running *npm install @reduxjs/toolkit* try restarting your server.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to install React Redux
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit